# Implementing API Gateway for ASP.NET API Microservices

Tags: .net, asp.net-web-api, asp.net-core, microservices, api-gateway

I have developed my micro-services using ASP.NET Core WEB API. I am still planning and investigating at this step to add an API Gateway that can act just as a proxy and routes client requests to the designated service (just to isolate and prevent clients from calling the services directly). The gateway will also perform logging and security checks.

I don't need any Discovery Mechanisms for the time being (but if there is a platform I could leverage that would be great).

For constraint purposes let's say that my micro-services are hosted on static IPs.

As far as creating my own API-Gateway, what things do I need to do?
How would such gateway be implemented?
How should I host it?  How many?
I need some patterns that I can translate into a generic implementation.

I was thinking about a simply structured DB that maps every API requested to a micro-service API at the other end, then using HttpWebRequest to construct the request and return back the response. Then I can create a message handler that can log all the requests.

Answer (score 2):

You can have a look here for an example: [Service Fabric gateway prototype](https://github.com/weidazhao/Hosting/tree/master/Microsoft.ServiceFabric.AspNetCore.Gateway)

This is specific for Service Fabric, but the concept is generically valid.

My experience with it is positive, anyway I've switched to [Azure Application Gateway](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/application-gateway/application-gateway-introduction) because all my microservices are hosted on Azure.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at the `Proxy library for ASP.NET Core` at https://github.com/aspnet/Proxy

This library also has support for WebSockets.